# Strange cornerRadius behaviour on UIView from xib

Tags: swift, uiview, uikit, xib, cornerradius

I created a custom `Numpad` keyboard through `xib` and wanted to initialize it with a rounded corners.

Here is the code I use:

```
import UIKit

class NumpadView: UIView {

@IBOutlet weak var resetButton: NumpadButton!
@IBOutlet weak var decimalButton: NumpadButton!

var target: UITextInput?
var view: UIView?

init(target: UITextInput, view: UIView) {
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    self.target = target
    self.view = view
    initializeSubview()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    initializeSubview()
}

func initializeSubview() {
    let xibFileName = "NumpadView"
    let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(xibFileName, owner: self, options: nil)![0] as! UIView
    self.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    self.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.addSubview(view)
    view.frame = self.bounds
    self.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
}
}
```

But then I receive the strange view look in area where `cornerRadius` is implemented:

[image]

How to remove that grey background which is visible near the rounded corners?

**UPDATE:**

According to View Debugger it seems like this grey layer between yellow square and `Visual Effect View` is a `UICompatibilityInputViewController`:

[image]

How I presenting the `Numpad`:

1.I created a `NumpadView` as a `UIView` subclass in a `xib`:

[image]

2.In my VC I just change a standard `textField.inputView` property on my custom `NumpadView`:

```
import UIKit

class NumpadViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupKeyboardHide()
    textField.delegate = self
    textField.inputView = NumpadView(target: textField, view: view)
}
}
```

Test project on [Github](https://github.com/artexhibit/CustomNumpad)

Comment: "How to remove that grey background" Step one: find out what it is! Use the View Debugger, it will tell you instantly.

Comment: @matt , thank you for the reply. According to View Debugger it is UICompatibilityInputViewController. Seems this is a grey view behind my visual effect: https://share.cleanshot.com/wOs9bN Tried to google but don't have any tips how to get rid of it or change its background color...

Comment: Right, so all of this, both questions, depends on how you are presenting this numpad view. But you totally omitted that info from your questions (both). Is it a keyboard extension? A presented view controller? What? How does this thing get onto the screen? Tell us.

Comment: @matt , thank you. Updated the question with a needed information

Comment: This is not your view. You can hack your way up the view hierarchy to it and make it `.clear`; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999818/ios-8-custom-input-view-background-color. That answers both of your questions.

Comment: @matt, thank you very much. Will try to sort it out, I am not good with Objective-C

Comment: There might be nothing you can do. This, as I said, is not your view. As long as you are going to use `inputView` or `inputViewController`, you are in a secondary system window and what's in it is not up to you.

Comment: @matt, got it. Then which alternatives I have? Avoid using of inputView and animate in and out my xib NumpadView. Then I lost all inputView built-in functionality...

Comment: That's right. As long as you rely on the runtime to present this as a keyboard for you, you are in the hands of the runtime. Welcome to the world of massive app frameworks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option to get your "rounded corners"...

Get rid of the `Visual Effect View` in your Numpad class, and set a layer mask on the superview at run-time.

**In `class NumpadView: UIView, UIInputViewAudioFeedback`**:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    guard let sv = superview else { return }
    let maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let bez = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds, cornerRadius: 16)
    maskLayer.path = bez.cgPath
    sv.layer.mask = maskLayer
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi, DonMag. Thank you for the suggestion! Could you please clarify for my understanding: if we get rid of Visual Effect View, then maskLayer is responsible for the blur effect in the solution? Can I use different blur styles here?

Comment: @artexhibit - no... we're applying the mask to this view's **superview**. When you set `textField.inputView = ...` the "built-in" blur effect is the superview of your custom view. You *could* use Debug View Hierarchy to figure out where you need to walk up/down the run-time hierarchy to "find" the effect view and manipulate it (or hide it and use your own), but that would be a lot of effort and would be guaranteed to work in the future.

Comment: Got it, thank you for explanation. I will also try to animate the numpadView in and out in textField delegate methods instead of inputView usage. In that case I will receive a full control over blur and cornerRadius as well

Comment: @artexhibit - obviously, there are pros and cons to each approach. Using it as an `.inputView` gives you everything built-in to the keyboard... using it as a subview gives you more control of the appearance and placement on the screen, but you have more work to do -- such as preventing the keyboard from showing when the field is "active."

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the NumpadView object has rounded corner. However, you are using it like this:

```
textField.inputView = NumpadView(target: textField, view: view)
```

So, that part which is not rounded is the textField's inputView. I'm not quite sure if you can modify its layer to have corner radius. But, if you really want to get that rounded corner effect, an easier approach is just to add the NumpadView directly to the parent view and anchored to the bottom. Then show it via the begin editing delegate of the textfield (and hide via end editing).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. I think I will stick to your tip. Should I set an exact NumpadView width and height in that scenario? Because now I am using self.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight] when initializing the view

Comment: Why not just use autolayout?